# Java: TreeSet with multiple objects that compare as equal using compareTo()?

Tags: java, collections, tree, comparison, duplicates

I am wondering if there is a way to get around uniqueness of objects w.r.t. `compareTo()` / `Comparator.compare()` method. For example, suppose I have the class

```
class MyClass extends Comparable<MyClass> {
  int value;
  // ... plenty of other fields
  public int compareTo(MyClass other) { ... // compares using the value field }
}
```

and would like to put different instances of MyClass into a TreeSet. By different, I mean if the default `equals()` would have returned `false` for two inserted objects, both should remain in the TreeSet.

Of course, a way to implement this with "high" probability of correctness would by having *compareTo()* method first check the `value` field and in case of a tie resolve it by comparing the `hashCode()` value.

I doubt there exist a way to achieve the desired behavior, since Java doesn't offer a safe way to cast references to a comparable type (unlike C/C++). However, if anybody has an idea please let me know.

Otherwise, is there an easier alternative than rewriting a TreeSet from scratch, or a less clumsy one than using `TreeMap<K, HashSet<K>>`?

Comment: it may be helpful to show the compareTo and equals in full

Answer (score 0):

Add an internal uniqueId to each instance.  You could use an AtomicLong or UUID to generate said uniqueId.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TreeMultiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html) from Guava, or a similar class from another library.

Answer (score 0):

If third-party libraries are fair game, I might implement this with [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) using

```
SetMultimap<Integer, MyClass> multimap = 
    MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().hashSetValues().build();
```

...which is like a `TreeMap<Integer, Set<MyClass>>`, but [significantly nicer to use](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap).

Notably, it's not a good design idea to use `MyClass` as the "tree" keys when you're actually using a different notion of equality.  Instead, pull out the key you're actually comparing on -- `Integer`, from what it looks like in your code.